# Subscription not Binding data to Input decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

When getting data from a subscription, my data is not being binded to my local variable.

I have two components, and a service. The parent component invokes a method from a service to do to an http get, the get includes a user object which I need to bind.
However, when console.logging the object outside the subscription it appears undefined.

Here is my code:

Parent Component:

```
selectedUser : User;
  onUserRowSelect(event): void {
    this.router.navigate(['../childComponent'], { relativeTo: this.route });

    this.formService.getUser(event.data.USER_ID).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result); // <-- Object is logged properly.
      this.selectedUser = result; // Assigning the local @Input variable to the result
    });
  }
```

Child Component:

```
  @Input() selectedUser : User;

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.selectedUser); // Returns undefined.
      }
```

Service with Http:

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    const _url = 'myURL/getuser/' + id;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
        .map(response => {
            const responseAsObject = response.json();
            this.myUser = responseAsObject;
            return responseAsObject;
        });
}
```

So my issue lies with selectedUser appearing undefined in the child component even after adding @input decorator to the variable.

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: Reactive forms template, but my form arent the issue

Comment: but how do we know you pass the data into the child component? infact, looking at your code, you never pass the data to the child as you claim to do it by `this.selectedUser = result;` but that isnt how the `@Input()` works

Comment: do you pass `selectedUser` into the custom component html in your parent html file?

Comment: we really need the html to reproduce your case

Comment: in fact, my template doesn't reference the selectedUser, so Input shouldn't be used in that case? My end result should be the data members of selected user such as selectedUser.name, selectedUser.lastName, etc..

Comment: the parent component is a list of users, the child component is a form menu to edit the selected user, since I want to pass user to the child component to edit. the selectedUser always appears undefined in the child component, but then again I think I'm using @Input decorator wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is asynchronous, so when your child component is initialized, `selectedUser` will be `undefined` in both parent and child, since you have apparently not initialized it. That doesn't matter though, as mentioned this is asynchronous. It takes a while for the response to come. To watch for changes in the `@Input` you can use the life cycle `OnChanges`, which is triggered whenever changes happens to the `@Input` variable. So in your child do:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.selectedUser) {
    console.log(this.selectedUser)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is to add a catch operator to the HTTP GET method.
In that catch, you can log if an error occurred. If an error is occurring then your variable will remain undefined.

```
return this.http.get(_url, options)
    .map(response => {
        const responseAsObject = response.json();
        this.myUser = responseAsObject;
        return responseAsObject;
    })
    .catch(error => log(error));
```

After adding the catch operator open your browser console and check if an error occurred then check your server.